# Install Jetty After Tomcat installed

Tags: maven, tomcat, jetty

I have been using Tomcat integrated with Eclipse for a long time, and now I want to try Jetty with maven without Eclipse (I am not using m2Eclipse for now). I know Jetty is using tomcat as container, and port will still be default 8080. Before doing anything reckless and screw up my setting, I would like to know that if any conflict could arise, and things to watch out for.  If I just put jetty-plugin to the pom.xml in a separate project, will that affect my other projects build on tomcat with Eclipse?

Thank you.

Comment: Jetty is its own web container, it does not use Tomcat.

Comment: I must have confused it with JBoss. Either way, the example I read about maven Jetty still put port to 8080, which would conflict with tomcat. Can I just use jetty plugin to pom.xml, and it won't affect tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run jetty and you already have tomcat running on port 8080 then that will not work, only one or the other can use a single port.  The solution is simple though, either set a different port in the jetty-maven-plugin configuration (8090?) or set no port and in the output of the plugin running it will have a line about the SelectChannelConnector or ServerConnector starting on port ###.  Simply use that in your browser for the port.

[edit] I'll also note that should you have tomcat running on 8080 and you startup jetty and it tries to use 8080, the *jetty* process will fail and the tomcat process will be completely unaffected.  The same as if the roles we reversed.

Comment: Thanks, I just change my Tomcat port.